# What are those mandatory tables that are required in a valid MSI package?

Tags: windows-installer

I was trying to create a MSI package from scratch by making use of the ORCA tool. I wanted an installer that does nothing but still to be a valid package from the MSI package perspective. I added only two tables to the package: InstallUISequence and InstallExecuteSequence. I added them because I just wanted to support normal install initiated using the /i switch of the msiexec. When I executed the package it gave an error.

I want to know the minimum mandatory tables that are required for a MSI package to be a valid package. Also, I would like to know the reason behind those tables being mandatory.

Note: Learning is the only objective behind this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that the starting point for you is [Windows Installer documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc185688.aspx). As for the minimal set of required tables for a valid MSI package, I think you should take advantage of running ICE validation. In Orca, select Tools > Validate..., choose "Full MSI validation suite" and press Go. The invalid package won't pass that validation. Each ICE error/warning has sufficient description on MSDN. and finally, when running the installation, generate a verbose log - it can answer all the questions. Happy learing! :)

Comment: +1 for running ICEs. Nice way to figure out on what is missing.

Answer (score 3):

You can find a good tutorial here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367563(VS.85).aspx

Also, a sample MSI with all the required tables is **uisample.msi** from the [Windows SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c17ba869-9671-4330-a63e-1fd44e0e2505&displaylang=en).